# What is the best way to ensure that the IEquatable.Equals implementation and the Object.Equals override return the same result?

Tags: c#

Please see the code below:

```
public virtual bool Equals(Entity other)
        {
            return Equals((Object)other);
        }

public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var compareTo = obj as Entity;
            if (ReferenceEquals(compareTo, null))
                return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, compareTo))
                return true;
            if (GetType() != compareTo.GetType())
                return false;
            if (!IsTransient() && !compareTo.IsTransient() && Id == compareTo.Id)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

`IEquatable.Equals` and `Object.Equals` override should return the same result.  Therefore if there is a call to `IEquatable.Equals` then it just calls the override for `Object.Equals`.

Is this a standard approach? I am trying to follow the principle of least astonishment.  Alternatively I could just duplicate the code in both methods.

Comment: "Is this a standard approach?" - define standard. But it seems to be a simple and working approach.  "Alternatively I could just duplicate the code in both methods" - definitely no. Already forgot the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle I mentioned in an answer to that other question of yours 6 hours ago?

Comment: Most of the time the `Equals(object)` override defers to the strongly-typed method, but it's a wash either way.

Comment: That direction involves more casting and type checking (which has readability issues as well as runtime costs), compared to the other direction shown by @mmathis.

Comment: Note that it only gets worse if you want to also apply a total order via `IComparable<T>` or `<` and `>` operators. What I do in that case is make *one* private method that takes (T t1, T t2), and returns -1, 0 or 1, and then every public facing comparison method calls it. See https://ericlippert.com/2013/10/07/math-from-scratch-part-six-comparisons/ for an example.

Comment: @Eric Lippert, could you explain what Zero means in that link? It appears to be a variable that is not declared anywhere.

Comment: @w0051977: That's part six of a long series where I build up integer arithmetic starting from nothing other than objects representing Zero and One.  They're defined in part two. If you want to understand the whole series, start reading it from the beginning rather than from part six. The link to part six was to answer the narrow question of how to define consistent comparison operators.

Comment: @Eric Lippert, I have asked a follow on question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48582699/equality-for-a-dateofbirth-value-object?noredirect=1#comment84165003_48582699.  If you are willing to take a look, then please do.

Comment: @EricLippert, that's not always a wanted approach. Some types have total order, but do not compare equal, think `NaN`, not equal to itself, but has order, and `INF`, similar story. Also, comparison can be more expensive in certain situations than "just" equality checking.

Comment: @Abel: Designing types that have non-standard comparisons, including values that are not equal to themselves, and so on, is for experts only. If you're such an expert then you already know how to do it correctly and safely without my advice! The vast majority of C# programmers are not designing such types, and are not experts on comparison logic; those developers should learn the rules and carefully follow them. The techniques I'm describing are to help programmers new to these concepts be successful in writing correct, robust code the first time.

Comment: @ericlippert, good points, I wholeheartedly agree :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The more standard approach I have seen is with the methods defined the other way around:

```
public virtual bool Equals(Entity other)
    {
        return other != null && ID == other.ID;
    }

public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Entity);
    }
```

This way you don't have to worry about checking that the types match, as that's taken care of already. As DocBrown mentioned in the comments, though, the important thing is that you don't duplicate the code between methods - have one method call the other. If your implementation above is working for you, there's not much reason to change it.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance of C# but, doesn't `obj as Entity` perform a cast? Won't that throw an exception rather than return the (desired) `false`?

Comment: @Maybe_Factor, no, `as` performs a type check and returns `null` if the check fails (including if the value is `null`), otherwise it performs the cast. Roughly speaking.

Comment: @Maybe_Factor As mentioned by @DavidArno, `as` is a "safe" cast, in that it will never throw an exception. If the object is not of the type, it returns null. `(Entity)object` *will* throw an exception if `object` is not of type `Entity`